# Cdh to hdp hive

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, hdp

I have written hive udf in cloudera and we’re migrating it to hortonworks. When I try to apply the same udf in hortonworks cluster it throws me an error below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the right dependencies with the correct versions. Sit with admin team regarding the versions and try to run it. Limit always scan few records and apply the operation on that data instead of whole dataset so, it worked for me when I apply the udf with limit. Even any version you use/even cdh version will work if you use limit. But the problem comes when you apply it on whole data set. As my sample data is around 5 million records, it has to run map reduce job.